# Can not install npm even after installing and defining path variable

Tags: node.js, npm

I have installed Node.js and have my path variable defined. Even then, when I try `install npm` in Git bash, I get:

> install missing destination file operand after 'npm' Try 'install --help' for more information

Answer (score 0):

You should switch arguments in your command:

```
npm install
```

Answer (score 0):

$ npm install

Command 'npm' not found, but can be installed with:

sudo apt install npm